# Reference contains five authors (reference writing)

Tags: biblatex, author-number

When you use `bibtex` to write references that contain more than three authors, not all names appear, but only the first name and others appear

How can I show the names of all authors

Example

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

    @article{RN63a,
       author = {Xu, Liyun and Chen, Yanhao and Briand, Florent and Zhou, Fengxu and Givanni, Moroni},
       title = {Reliability Measurement for Multistate Manufacturing Systems with Failure Interaction},
       journal = {Procedia CIRP},
       volume = {63},
       pages = {242-247},
       ISSN = {2212-8271},
       year = {2017},
       type = {Journal Article}
    }
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  style=numeric, 
  sortcites,
  backend=biber,
  giveninits=true % <===================================================
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given} % <============================
\renewcommand*\newunitpunct{\addcomma\space} % <========================


\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
This document is an example of BibTeX using in bibliography management. 
Three items are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book 
\cite{RN63a}.

\medskip

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: More information is required to answer your question. Please provide a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: @gusbrs see new update

Comment: Add `maxbibnames=99` to your biblatex's options (99 being an arbitrary high number).